# Travelling to Greece with a refugee travel document while green card is still being processed

Tags: schengen, paperwork, greece

I plan to travel from the U.S. to Greece. I have my refugee travel document but my green card application is still being processed. I have all the paperwork but I'm still waiting to be officially given the green card. My question is will I still be able to get the Schengen visa without the green card? I have my U.S. work permit and everything else. Please advise! There is a requirement to have a green card to get a visa through Greece http://www.mfa.gr/usa/en/services/services-for-non-greeks/visa-section.html

Comment: Probably.  There's no requirement for a refugee to have a green card before getting a Schengen visa.  But the only way to know for sure is to apply and see what happens.

Comment: great! yeah i called the greek embassy but got two different answers. one saying as long as he has the paperwork for the green card it's fine, but then another person said maybe not.oh and the visa requirement does say to have a green card. it's quite confusing

Comment: Can you edit your question to include a link supporting the green card requirement?

Comment: You have misunderstood.  The requirement to have "a valid Alien Resident Card or a visa to the U.S. (except for B1/B2)" is for you to be able to apply for a visa *at a Greek consulate in the United States.*  If you were in Melbourne, the analogous requirement would be to have "proof of your visa status in Australia (visa label on your passport or e-mail notification from VEVO directly sent to the e-mail of the consular mission)."  Anyway, if you read the US requirement closely, you'll see that other visa types are allowed; any proof of your current legal status in the US should suffice.

Comment: The I-571 is sufficient to prove legal status in the US. You don't need the green card for that.

Comment: Ok thanks, I have an appointment to go to the Greek embassy in DC (where I live) to give them all my information. The link I included is from the Greek embassy and I thought it meant I have to prove my status with a Green Card. We will see!

Comment: @brogs885 any further comment?

Comment: READ THE FOLLOWING: [USCIS](http://www.uscis.gov/green-card/green-card-processes-and-procedures/travel-documents/emergency-travel), [NOLO Law for All](http://www.nolo.com/legal-encyclopedia/free-books/fiance-marriage-visa-book/chapter14-24.html) and [an insurance site](http://www.travelinsurancereview.net/2010/03/31/are-you-able-to-travel-out-of-the-us-while-awaiting-your-green-card/), you'll need to be _very careful_ not to lose your application status.

Answer (score 2):

While the Green Card would be great but the [page you linked](http://www.mfa.gr/usa/en/services/services-for-non-greeks/visa-section.html) actually states:

> 2. A valid Alien Resident Card or **a visa to the U.S.** (except for B1/B2).

Basically you will have a sufficient proof that you reside in the United States so that consulate has reasonable expectation that you're applying in the appropriate location.

Work Permit will likely be sufficient to prove residency in the US.